# 2013 Solution Migration

Tags: 2013, error, migration, solution-package, solution-deployment

I upgraded a site with custom aspx pages from 2010 to 2013 and tried to save it as a template to move it to another SP13 farm but I keep getting an error.

The content type name '

> $Resources:ReportServerResources,DataSourseContentTypeName;' cannot
>   contain:/:*?#%<>~, two consecutive periods (..), or special
>   characters such as tab.

Any ideas? I am at a complete loss.

Comment: Its complaining about failure to get content type name from resource files. Do you have Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint installed? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/deb11087-13ae-4380-8363-642647be48ed/how-to-get-rid-of-resourcesreportserverresourcesreportserversitesettingsgrouptitle?forum=sharepointadmin